# splits the input into two subset (SMQT)

Tags: image, matlab

I have an image matrix and i need to split this matrix into two subsets with two condition.

For example D(x)  is the image matrix

```
        D0(x) = {x | V(x) ≤ mean(V(:)), ∀x ∈ D}

        D1(x) = {x | V(x) > mean(V(:)), ∀x ∈ D}
```

where `V(x)` is the intensity at pixel `x`. thanks in advance.

Comment: what is V(x)? what do you mean by V(x)>V(x)??

Comment: sorry second V(x) is mean(V(:))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
M = zeros(size(V));
M(V>mean(V(:))) = 1;
D1 = M.*V;
D0 = ~M.*V;
```

Comment: thanks for answer @lennon310  but D0 and D1 must be contain V matris values. ı tried this code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
V=imread('cameraman.tif');

[x y]=size(V);
Ort=mean(V(:));
D1=im;
D0=im;

  for i=1:x

     for j=1:y

        if ( V(i,j)<= Ort )
            D0(i,j)=V(i,j); 
            D1(i,j)=0;
        else
            D0(i,j)=0;
            D1(i,j)=V(i,j);
        end

     end
 end
```